# Hibernate: MultiTableBulkIdStrategy bug when using custom schema?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, database-schema

I'm rolling my own version of

```
 class PhysicalNamingStrategyWithDynamicSchema() : org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl(){

override fun toPhysicalSchemaName(name: Identifier?, context: JdbcEnvironment): Identifier? {
    return super.toPhysicalSchemaName(Identifier("schemaName", false), context)
}
```

}

and registering it with

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: PhysicalNamingStrategyWithDynamicSchema
```

to provide application instance specific schema names (in reality `"schemaName"` is determined on-the-fly)

This seems to work fine unless some bulk operation is going on, for which hibernate is creating temporary ("HT_*") tables.

This looks like this:

```
create temporary table HT_tableName (id int8 not null)
```

However, it then (wrongly?) qualifies the temporary tableName with the schemaName when it tries to fill the temporary table in preparation for the bulk operation, which looks something like this:

```
 insert into
    schemaName.HT_tableName
    select
        tableName.id as id 
    from
        ( select ... )
```

This leads to an error.
Is this a bug or misconfiguration? Is there a better way of solving this, other than to create a custom MultiTableBulkIdStrategy as a workaround?

I know I could use a different `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: MultiTableBulkIdStrategy` to avoid temporary table creation at all but I like to stick with it for performance reasons. The `LocalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy` has the same issue.